# Connect jQuery to a REST Service

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I'm trying to use a jQuery example that uses **jtable** to connect to a back-end service.(https://www.simplecodestuffs.com/pagination-in-java-web-applications-using-jquery-jtable-plugin/). I've adapted it to reach a REST Service that produces and consumes data as JSON:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/metro/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
            title : 'Students List',
            paging: true, //Enable paging
            pageSize: 3, //Set page size (default: 10)           
            actions: {
                listAction: 'http://localhost:8080/Controller/list',
                createAction:'http://localhost:8080/Controller/create',
                updateAction: 'http://localhost:8080/Controller/update',
                deleteAction: 'http://localhost:8080/Controller/delete'
            },
            fields : {
                id : {
                    title : 'id',
                    sort :true,
                    width : '30%',
                    key : true,
                    list : true,
                    edit : false,
                    create : true
                },
                name : {
                    title : 'Name',
                    width : '30%',
                    edit : true
                },
                department : {
                    title : 'Department',
                    width : '30%',
                    edit : true
                },
                emailId : {
                    title : 'Email',
                    width : '20%',
                    edit : true
                }
            }
        });
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div
        style="width: 80%; margin-right: 10%; margin-left: 10%; text-align: center;">
        <h4>Pagination in Java Web Applications jTable</h4>
        <div id="StudentTableContainer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the jQuery code is unable to connect to the REST Service :"An error occured while communicating to the server."
However, REST services are correctly working if I try to request them via curl. Can anyone give me a clue what is wrong with the above code?

EDIT: I've captured from the Firefox debugger a trace of what is happening. It seems there's an error when requesting a 'list?jtStartIndex=0&jtPageSize=3' with a POST. How can I configure it to use instead a GET http://localhost:8080/Controller/list ?
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Are there any more details about the error?  Is the AJAX request made and a response received in the network tab of the browser's debugging tools?  A stack trace from DataTables?  Anything else?

Comment: Thanks, I've uploaded a trace from FireFox network debugger....it seems it's hitting the wrong URI and the wrong HTTP Method but I don't know how to fix it :-(

Comment: That HTTP request looks right to me, and seems to match the documentation: http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/Actions#act-listAction  It looks like the server-side code is returning a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error.  Is the server-side code not permitting the request?

Comment: Ok, I've figured out that the error happens because  the "list" action on the Server side is an HTTP GET Method. I have to find a way to configure the action 'http://localhost:8080/Controller/list' to send a GET request instead of a POST

Comment: As the problem turns out to be more specific, I'll open another thread.

Comment: My suggestion is to test first REST services and then integrate into your code. To do so, my suggestion is to use something like Postman or Insomnia. You should try some extensions in Firefox like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/resting/?src=external-stackoverflow so you don't have an external system overhead

Answer (score 0):

Try using the  [jtable ajax settings](https://jtable.org/ApiReference/GeneralOptions#genopt-ajaxSettings) as per documented example

```
ajaxSettings: {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
}
```